# How to edit/update an object in an array and keep all other nested data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update purely just the firstName, lastName and profile for an object without destroying any other data within that object...

Here's an example of the current state.

```
  state = {
    children: [
      {
        id: 1,
        firstName: 'Bella',
        lastName: 'Laupama',
        profile: 'child_care',
        schedules: [
          {
            id: 1,
            date: '25 December, 2018',
            parent: 'Chris',
            activity: 'Christmas'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            date: '28 December, 2018',
            parent: 'Mischa',
            activity: 'Christmas with Malane Whanau'
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            date: '31 December, 2018',
            parent: 'Laura',
            activity: 'New Years Eve'
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            date: '1 January, 2019',
            parent: 'Laura',
            activity: 'New Years Day'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

And here's the current function I'm trying to pass it to update the current state...

```
      editChild = (first, last, prof) => {
        var updatedChild = {
          firstName: first,
          lastName: last,
          profile: prof
        }
        var children = this.state.children

        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
          if (children[i].firstName === first) {
            children[i] = updatedChild
          }
        }
        this.setState({ children })
      }

**UPDATE**

Here's the code where I'm calling the function ( from a child component )

export default class EditChild extends React.Component {
  state = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    profile: '',
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.editChild(this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName, this.state.profile)
    // Final validation before submitting to server
    console.log('SUBMITTED:', this.state)
    // Clear the state to clear the form
    this.setState({
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      profile: ''
    })
  }
```

...form etc is in the render etc...

The form works fine and console logs the result like this:

```
SUBMITTED: 
{firstName: "Donald", lastName: "Trump", profile: "face"}
```

**UPDATE**

Thank you to @Tholle and @charlietfl for leading me in the right direction. Basically I needed to be passing the ID as well, and not trying to match based off the first name, as the first name is obviously something that can be changed from the edit form as well. So if I changed Bella Laupama to Charlie Chaplan, it wouldn't find the id.

So I used @Tholle code and modified it to search and replace by id and it worked perfectly :)

```
 editChild = (id, first, last, prof) => {
    var updatedChild = {
      firstName: first,
      lastName: last,
      profile: prof
    }

    this.setState(prevState => {
      const children = [...prevState.children]
      const childIndex = children.findIndex(child => child.id === id)

      children[childIndex] = { ...children[childIndex], ...updatedChild }

      return { children }
    })
    console.log(this.state)
  }
```

Comment: Just matching first names seems very flaky since in general first names aren't unique. Don't you have a reference to the original object at the time you are editing it? Show how you use `editChild()`

Comment: if you do a console.log after `if (children[i].firstName === first)`, do you get something when you would expect it? Also I don't think this is what you want... this would remove the `schedules` and `id` properties.

Comment: @charlietfl I just updated the post to show the editChild() in action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the index of the child with [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and then replace the object with that index in a new array with a copy of the original object with all the properties in `updatedChild` added to it.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    children: [
      {
        id: 1,
        firstName: "Bella",
        lastName: "Laupama",
        profile: "child_care",
        schedules: [
          {
            id: 1,
            date: "25 December, 2018",
            parent: "Chris",
            activity: "Christmas"
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            date: "28 December, 2018",
            parent: "Mischa",
            activity: "Christmas with Malane Whanau"
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            date: "31 December, 2018",
            parent: "Laura",
            activity: "New Years Eve"
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            date: "1 January, 2019",
            parent: "Laura",
            activity: "New Years Day"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  editChild = (first, last, prof) => {
    var updatedChild = {
      firstName: first,
      lastName: last,
      profile: prof
    };

    this.setState(prevState => {
      const children = [...prevState.children];
      const childIndex = children.findIndex(child => child.firstName === first);

      children[childIndex] = { ...children[childIndex], ...updatedChild };

      return { children };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</div>
        <button onClick={() => this.editChild("Bella", "Doe", "Programmer")}>
          Edit child
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you're looking for using ES6 Object spread syntax:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    firstName: "Bill",
    lastName: "Gates",
    age: 2018
  };

  update = (firstName, lastName) => {
    const newObj = { firstName, lastName };
    this.setState({ ...newObj });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>
        <button onClick={() => this.update("Steve", "Jobs")}>
          Click to update
        </button>
        <hr />
        {this.state.firstName} {this.state.lastName} {this.state.age}
      </h1>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

CodeSandbox example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/3qww0l20xq).

What's happening here with `this.setState({ ... newObj })` is that any values in `this.state.` which have the keys which match the keys in `newObj` will be overwritten with the values from `newObj`, and leave the other values unchanged.